# In django, is there a recommended way to store models that contain executable python code?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to design a django app for extensibility. Within the model, I have an Object class. I'd like to be able to define Scripts that operate on objects and return values according to a predefined API. The program will eventually include hundreds of Scripts, so building a straightforward system to manage them is key.

A few additional specs:

- I need to store information about Scripts (e.g. a description field)
- I'd like to be able to use these Script fields in views and forms with a minimum of hassle.
- Security is not a big concern -- I'll be writing these scripts myself; I just need a clean way to catalog them.

There are several kludgy ways of doing this, such as tacking the executable code from each Script onto the Object model, and then creating a Scripts table to hold the extra fields. But none seems like a good OOP solution.

I'm looking for clean ways to build the system. It seems like the key question is where code for Scripts should be housed. Options: in the DB, the Object model, separate helper functions, external python scripts...

Suggestions?

**Clarification**

I chatted with Chris about getting past the XY problem on this question. Here are some details that helped clarify things.

Most Objects in this app are text. Scripts run analysis on them -- things like "count the number of words in the document," or "check to see if a famous person from this list is named." Scripts interact with objects according to an API that specifies what arguments get passed and returned. There will be lots of scripts, and they will contain executable code, as well as other metadata. We'll want to do things such as populate tables listing scripts and their descriptions.

Comment: Sounds like a casebook example of an XY Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but I don't think this is an XY problem. I need to build a django app with one unusual feature: it associates executable code with "normal" model fields. I'm looking for suggestions on how to design that kind of system architecture. Most of the other information in the question is probably extraneous, but I wanted to help people zero in on the specifics of the question. Broad questions about system architecture can be harder than specific "help me debug this thing" questions, but stackoverflow has room for both.

Comment: That was pretty much the XY Problem I was referencing ;). The idea of storing executable code that will run in the context of your application in a model of that application almost makes me recoil in horror. Maybe there's a perfectly logical reason to do this, but I can't think of one and you haven't alluded to one. So really the question is why do you "need" to do that in the first place?

Comment: Yep, I know it's a strange use case -- that's why I'm asking for suggestions. I don't know that more specifics are going to help much. I have objects--text, mostly--and scripts to run analysis on them. A script might do something like "count the number of words in the document," or "check to see if a famous person from this list is named." Scripts interact with objects according to an API that specifies what arguments get passed and returned.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that storing code in the DB is the way to go. It could very well go in a model file, or somewhere else. I suppose I could put scripts in another folder on the server and just call them via subprocess...

Comment: That was sort of my point. Why couldn't the "Script" just be a method or methods on the `Object` model? If it's an API for working with an `Object` it really *belongs* on the model. Am I missing something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5290/discussion-between-abe-and-chris-pratt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A potential solution, based on your chat with Chris, is what I'd call a function registry. I've used this sort of concept for a form builder where admins could write simple one line validation functions (which we processed using Sympy), but sometimes needed assistance from a more complicated function that we had to write in code.

Basically, you create a singleton class to which you bind functions using a decorator. Something like the following:

```
class FunctionRegistry(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = []

    def register(self, function):
        self.functions.append(function)

function_registry = FunctionRegistry()
```

You can then write a really simple decorator to add functions to the registry:

```
def registry_function(original_function):
    function_registry.register(original_function)
    return original_function
```

With those two tools, creating a new script is as simple as doing the following:

```
@registry_function
def my_script(foo):
    return process(foo)
```

You can do all sorts of crazy stuff with introspection in your function registry - my project gathers up docstrings and signatures so users can see descriptions of all the available functions. I've simplified the registry a lot here, but I'd be happy to provide a more detailed example on Django snippets if someone thinks it would be useful :-)

Comment: This is very cool. To fit the needs of my application, it looks like the FunctionRegistry functions object would need to be modified as a dictionary instead of a simple list. We could store function (aka script) metadata by passing arguments through the decorator. We could even use the FunctionRegistry.functions object to restrict the choices parameter in a model CharField. I'm starting to see the potential. Beautiful!